# Scroll a div to bottom automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a chat module for my website.  I have a div where my messages appear, and I want it to scroll to the bottom of the div when I open the chat page. Most recent messages appear at the bottom.

Here is the HTML and CSS code am using
/*CSS*/

```
#pageMiddle_message{
    margin-left:280px;
    background:#FFF;
    width: 700px;
    height: 592px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    position:fixed;
    border: orange 2px solid;
}
#message{
    width:auto;
    height:100px;
}
#chat{
    background:orange;
    color: #fff;
}
#no_chat{
    background:orange;
    color: #fff;
    height:42px;
    line-height:0.11857143em;
}
#head_chat{
    color:#fff;
    line-height: 0.82857143em;
}
.sub_paneln{
    text-transform:capitalize;
    color: #444;
    font-weight:500;
    background-size: 1px 1px;
    line-height: 0.82857143em;
    list-style:none;
}
.my_message{
     float:right;
     background-color:#DFFFFB;
     list-style:none;
     border-radius:8px;
     border: #39F 1px solid;
}
.their_message{
     float:left;
     background-color:#0ADEF5;
     border-radius:8px;
     list-style:none;
     border: #06F 1px solid;
     position:inherit;
}
.line_message{
    color: #444;
    font-weight:500;
    background-size: 1px 1px;
    line-height: 0.82857143em;
    list-style:none;
}
.message_list{
    background:#fff;
    padding:2px;
    height:445px;
    max-height:600px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position:relative;
}
.message_body{
    border-radius: 5px;
    height:auto;
}
#text_message{
    width:670px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-left:23px;
    background-color:#D2D2D2;
    padding:0px;
}

/*HTML*/
<div class="message_body">    
 <div id="message_list" class="message_list">messagelist</div>
 <div id="message" class="new_message" style="height:auto;"></div>
 <div style="background:#D2D2D2; height:97px; border-radius:4px;">
 <div id="text_message">
 <table width="" height="">
  <tr>
    <th width="auto" style="float:left;">
    <a href=""><img src="" width="60" height="60" style="border-radius:5px;"/>
    </a></th><th style="float:left;"><textarea name="sendmessage" style="width:579px; height:55px; border:orange 2px solid; border-radius:3px;" id="sendmessage" placeholder="send message to messager></textarea></th></th></tr></table>
    <div style="float:right; padding-right:4px; margin-right:15px; margin-top:-3px;">
<input name="send" type="submit" value="send message" onClick="javascript:ajax_send();">
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you give us more details? What does your code look like so far?

Comment: I have uploaded the code... Let me know what u think guys

Answer (score 0):

You could, using jQuery, calculate the bottom of the div and then scroll to it:

```
var $div = $("message_list");
var divpos = $div.offset();
var divheight = $div.height();
var divbottom = divpos.top + divheight;
var windowheight = $(window).height();
$(window).scrollTop(divbottom - windowheight);
```

The variables are used to calculate the bottom of the div, and then `$(window).scrollTop()` scrolls to the passed position.  `divbottom - windowheight` makes the page scroll such that the bottom of the div matches the bottom of the screen.